# Have I actually found something or is this just a 100+ coincidence cognates? indo-european, sino-tibetan, austroneisian, japanese, korean

Tags: proto-indo-european, japanese, korean, austronesian, sino-tibetan

I like comparing languages on my free time and found that Eurasian languages have a lot in common and I couldn't quite place my finger on it but the languages just seemed similar.  One time I compared Austro-asiatic to proto-korean-japanese(PKJ) believing they could be related due to both being O2 haplogroup populations, I had also put Hmong-Mienic in the swadesh list just grasping for any sort of relation.  I didn't find any similarities between native words but the PST loanwords in Hmong sounded a bit like words in PKJ and frequently words that had initial /m/ in PST had to do with darkness or evil and that matched a bit with PKJ.  I then constructed an eight proto-language long swadesh so that I didn't have to go one by one with comparisons and could just see which languages had similarities from a larger pool, I quickly found that PKJ, PIE(indo-european), austronesian, and (after some adjusting with affixes and word choice) PST had many similarities.  I started comparing them and just today started reconstructions so they are still vague.  Also what order would they be related in if at all?
here is the link to the google doc https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BBPPZz2NkWIK_HetLHDKecftSk2btmpCOJ0jXYk_yAs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Indo-European, Japanese and Korean are theorized to be related, the others, no. Most of your conjectured examples of cognates are very weak cases.

Comment: @Anixx whilst there are long-range comparative schools that do hypothesise that connection, consensus is that there is no provable connection and that the purported connections are not especially suggestive (unlike e.g. connections between IE and Uralic which whilst generally accepted as unproven are generally thought to be suggestive of some connection)

Comment: these families are generally accepted to be unconnected, and even long range comparativists do not connect all these families. It is technically possible that you have spotted something but it's extremely unlikely. It may be helpful for us to judge if you provide a list of correspondences and/or sound changes as well

Comment: @tristan that's weird when I compare them I don't find many similarities maybe I'll have to try again.

Comment: @thattouhounerd typically morphology is taken to be more indicative of shared descent than vocabulary as it's (generally) less easily borrowed. Looking at that there are some similarities in verbal and nominal inflection. The pronoun systems are also similar but (especially in the first and second persons) this seems to be a much broader trend observed across the heavily disputed Nostratic macrofamily (I've occasionally seen people, mostly conlangers rather than linguists, refer to these as the "mitian" languages after the 1p m- and 2p t-)

Comment: @Tristan I think my attempt is better but I was more downvoted: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/44947/apparent-sound-crespondences-between-eurasian-trans-new-guinean-pama-nyungan-a At least, I do not make conjectures based on one or two families.

Comment: @Anixx The people in your comments went after you lol.  Your reconstructions seemed pretty good to me but I don't have any degrees in anything I just think comparing languages is fun to do so what do I know?